# How to find top rows for every set of duplicate rows using sql?

Tags: sql

For example for a given table.

```
i  |  j   | v  |
---|------|----|
1  |  2   | 2  |
1  |  2   | 3  |
1  |  2   | 4  |
1  |  4   | 1  |
1  |  4   | 6  |
1  |  4   | 8  |
```

Comment: what rdbms and what do you mean top? Whats the order?

Answer (score 0):

From the question i am assuming that for every duplicate set of values in columns `i` and `j`, you are trying to retrieve `minimum` or `maximum` value row from `v`.

To get `max` row:

```
SELECT t1.i
    ,t1.j
    ,max(t1.v) AS v
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.i
    ,t1.j
ORDER BY t1.i
    ,t1.j
```

**Result:**

```
i | j | v
---------
1   2   4
1   4   8
```

To get `min` value row for v, replace `max` with `min` in above query.

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/NTOXC68986)**

Answer (score 0):

Try short code as below :

```
select i, j, MAX(v) v from #temp group by i, j
```

**Result:**

```
i | j | v
---------
1   2   4
1   4   8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp (i int, j int , k int)

insert into #temp values(1,2,2)
insert into #temp values(1,2,3)
insert into #temp values(1,2,4)
insert into #temp values(1,4,1)
insert into #temp values(1,4,6)
insert into #temp values(1,4,8)

SELECT * from #temp;

WITH CTE  as
(select *, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by j order by k)  rowno from #temp )
select i,j,k from cte where rowno = 1
```